# Setting visited on link in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I catch the click event on certain hyperlinks and instead open a jQuery UI dialog using the href. I return false to avoid the browser doing it too...

```
    $('a.previewable').click(function(){
            $('#dialog').html('<img src="'+$(this).attr('href')+'">');
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                    title: 'Preview',
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true
            });
            return false;
    });
```

It works great but the link color doesn't change to visited when I click on it. How can I tell the browser the link has indeed been visited?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since you did `return false`, it hasn't been visited. The best you could probably do is style it.

```
$(this).addClass('visited');
```

*css*

```
.visited {
    color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Though I'd make it `a:visited, a.visited { color: #00e; }` so that both actual visited links and links marked with the `visited` class are styled the same.

Answer (score 2):

These scenarios about adding a custom class are weird. What happens the next time the page is refreshed? Wouldn't you have to track all links that had the visited class and persist that information to a backend so it can be restored on subsequent requests? I'd think all those styles would be wiped out the next request since all logic is being done in memory, client side via JavaScript. The browser would normally maintain a cache and persist that information.

Comment: I'd agree - it would be much better if the information persisted. Is there a way to achieve that? Would an AJAX request in the UI dialog be better?

Comment: Well...it could be done, but you'd have to start sticking id's on your hyperlinks so you know how to retrieve then on the next refresh. The AJAX request would presumably work, but I wouldn't want to make a blind roundtrip to the server just to make the links turn purple. That is what you have in mind right? Just make the request to the server and not care about the response? If you do want to do that you'd better put etags on those images so they're not blindy served. I guess if you really want it to persist, then the latter would be the easiest approach.

Comment: No I was thinking of loading the contents of the href via AJAX into the dialog, so the browser is fetching the URL and would (hopefully?) count it as "visited"